# How to write one action for two form in cakephp?

Tags: html, cakephp, action

I'm working with cakephp3. I have a login_signup.ctp page that this two forms are in `<div class="tab-content">...</div>`. Do i have to write one action(login_signup()) or two action(login() and signup() )?

Is it possible to define the action for tab-content ? How can?

Is it possible each tab will be moved to two separate pages but with the same figure?

this is html code for tabs:

```
<div class="form">
<ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">signup</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">login</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">   
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="login">   
        ...
    </div>
</div><!-- tab-content -->
```

and this is my action in UserController :

```
 public function loginSignup() {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do i have to write one action(login_signup()) or two action(login() and signup() )?

Technically you don't have to but you *really should **not***. This is a principle called [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and considered best practice. One method should *never* do more than **one** thing, and it should do that **one** thing very well.

So have just a login action and register action and simple render the same view for both and point the forms to the matching action.

> Is it possible to define the action for tab-content ? How can?

Send a value within each form that you can check to identify which form you're dealing with. If you really want to do that.